# Azure based Umbraco site - when logging in, I get logged back out immediately

Tags: azure, umbraco, azure-worker-roles, azure-blob-storage

I have recently installed a website project on Azure and that was relatively easy to do thanks to great docs online. We are having a problem with the back office (admin) login though, it's a bit strange, as it didn't happen straight away, I shall elaborate....

When I go to http://www.keelycattschoolofdance.co.uk/umbraco/ it takes me to the login page, which seems fine.

(The url at this point becomes www.keelycattschoolofdance.co.uk/.../login.aspx)

I then login, which works and it starts to display the admin panels but then bounces back to the login and the URL becomes www.keelycattschoolofdance.co.uk/.../login.aspx

I am running this on Azure using the Accelerator, latest version of Umbraco and using SQL CE 4.0 rather than SQL Server.

has anyone seen this before?

Please let me know if you need more information, I shall respond :-)

Thanks in advance

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like it may be a Session error. This is a problem for Azure and Umbraco because Azure uses round robin load balancing.

The normal way of setting up an Umbraco site using the accelerator would be to have a separate session DB where the shared session state is stored.

Make sure you are using this accelerator for Umbraco on Azure as it's the latest and best.

http://waacceleratorumbraco.codeplex.com/

We have several large production sites using this and I can confirm they all work fine (including the backend editing environment).

Things to watch out for are that you need to follow the instructions closely as they are easy to get wrong :-)

Make sure you don't have dashes in your db names as this makes things go wrong as well.

Finally if you are using more than one web role the Umbraco preview can sometimes yellow screen, as the preview XML may not be on the server that gets to the preview request. This is again because of the round robin load balancing.

Comment: Thanks and this makes a lot of sense too, I am trying this out and will let you know how I get on :-)

Comment: Your suggestion was a big help and now as a result, I can run through these deployments far more easily than I could at first - thanks so much!